# Как создать определённый паттерн для переходов по ссылкам в asp.net 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, маршрутизация

Допустим такая ситуация:
Есть 2 странички

1. Регистрационная форма
2. Уведомление о успешной регистрации

Мне нужно как-то сделать так чтоб пользователь был способен увидеть 2 страничку только в случае если он успешно перешёл на неё из первой странички( то есть успешно заполнил регистрационную форму )
Если же какой то случайный пользователь просто введёт ссылку на 2 страницу, то он не увидит Уведомление о успешной регистрации, но его перекинет на главную страницу Index.

То есть только такой переход будет легальным

Register page -> Notification page

Как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, например, использовать сессию. В сессию запишите нужные вам данные при регистрации и проверяйте сессию на эти данные при открытии второй страницы.

Comment: а вообще, что вам мешает использовать одну страницу вместо двух? Новый человек приходит - показываете ему форму регистрации. Как он её отправит, если успешно регистрируется - показывате ему успех.